# slf4j and log4j log messages visible in the console but not appending into logfile

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have a problem with slf4j and log4j.. I can see the log messages in the console but those messages are not appending to the file

i am using the following jars.

```
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

My log4j.properties file is below.

```
    # Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

    # Direct log messages to a log file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\myLogFile.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}
 %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and I am getting the following warning in console when i am running my java class

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/1018835/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.10/logback-classic-1.0.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/1018835/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if file is present at the location.

Also see if your application has write access to the file.

Comment: Also has access ? Because I also faced the same problem, and solved by giving write access (777) to it.

Comment: that is not a problem.. i have seen a waring that multiple binding